# Bootstrap: Centering Elements Vertically and Horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where only a form exists and I want the form to be placed in the center of the screen.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Another label</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input">
      </div>
    </form>   
  </div>  
</div>
```

The `justify-content-center` aligns the form horizontally, but I can't figure out how to align it vertically. I have tried using both `align-items-center` and `align-self-center`, but neither seems to work.

---

A minimal reproducible example can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/xotonekita/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 515, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5 (Updated 2021)**

Bootstrap 5 is still *flexbox* based so vertical centering works the same way as it did in Bootstrap 4. For example, `align-items-center` (flex-direction: row) and `justify-content-center` (flex-direction: column) can used on the flexbox parent (row or d-flex).

[Centering examples in Bootstrap 5](https://codeply.com/p/0VM5MJ7Had)

**Vertical center (don't forget the parent must have a defined height!):**

- `my-auto` for centering *inside* flex (`.d-flex`) elements
- `my-auto` can be used to **center columns** (`.col-`) *inside* `row`
- `align-items-center` to **center columns** (`col-*`) *inside* `row`

**Horizontal center:**

- `text-center` to center `display:inline` elements & column content
- `mx-auto` for centering inside flex elements
- `mx-auto` can be used to **center columns** (`.col-`) inside `row`
- `justify-content-center` to **center columns** (`col-*`) inside `row`

---

**Bootstrap 4.3+ (Update 2019)**

There's **no need** for **extra CSS**. What's already included in Bootstrap will work. Make sure the container(s) of the form are **full height**. Bootstrap 4 now has a `h-100` class for 100% height...

**Vertical center:**

```
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <form class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Another label</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input">
      </div>
    </form>   
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/raCutAGHre

**the height of the container with the item(s) to center should be 100%**
(or whatever the desired height is relative to the centered item)

Note: When using `height:100%` (**percentage height**) on any element, the element [**takes in the height of it's container**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049918/171456). In modern browsers vh units `height:100vh;` can be used instead of `%` to get the desired height.

Therefore, you can set html, body {height: 100%}, or use the new `min-vh-100` class on container instead of `h-100`.

---

**Horizontal center:**

- `text-center` to center `display:inline` elements & column content
- `mx-auto` for centering inside flex elements
- `offset-*` or `mx-auto` can be used to **center columns** (`.col-`)
- `justify-content-center` to **center columns** (`col-*`) inside `row`

---

[Vertical Align Center in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252443/vertical-align-center-in-bootstrap-4/42252877#42252877)
[Bootstrap 4 full-screen centered form](https://www.codeply.com/go/GeBvYXxFKY)
[Bootstrap 4 center input group](https://www.codeply.com/go/yk1uKMtvdd)
[Bootstrap 4 horizontal + vertical center full screen](https://www.codeply.com/go/9HWnyQm2Sf)

Comment: Is it OK to use the `<section>` tag, or should one stick to `<div>`s for centering content horizontally and vertically in the viewport? I've got an existing site that's got pages with sections that change color and/or background images.

Comment: Shouldn't any direct child of row be a .col?

Comment: This answer is slightly broken. You explicitly state "there is NO NEED for additional CSS" but that is wrong. In your code sample it shows you must set body and html to be 100% in CSS outside of Bootstrap 4. Without this additional CSS your solution does not work.

Comment: No, body and html are not "outside".. Bootstrap CSS classes can be added to them too! https://www.codeply.com/go/5ifNMHKUEy @dawn.. what specifically didn't work? Your comment is not helpful.

Comment: Container didn't need 100% but `h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center` worked

Comment: That's why the answer says "or whatever the desired height is relative to the centered item"

Comment: did not center for me vertically... i just copy and pasted your code inside a <body>...</body> ... any thoughts?

Comment: I need to center a `<canvas>` tag horizontally. I have it inside a row and col so it looks like: `<div class="row"><div class="col"><canvas></div></div>`. How the heck do I center the canvas? I've tried to do this by applying display: inline; to the canvas then using text-center, another attempt was by applying the class d-flex to col and then applying mx-auto to row. I don't want to use offset if I don't have to. I tried it and it centered it... kind of. For some reason, justify-content-center isn't centering the canvas. Thoughts?

Comment: This worked perfectly. If you are looking for a quick PUG translated version: ```.row.h-100.justify-content-center.align-items-center```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for an overlap spinner in Bootstrap 5? (where you have a grey background taking up 100% of the width/height and spinner in the middle). I see they have an example of a centered modal with a static background but not with a pure spinner without the extra modal junk.

Comment: `m-auto` on a child inside an `h-100 d-flex` parent is all I actually needed to center one div within another.

Answer (score 36):

This work for me:

```
<section class="h-100">
  <header class="container h-100">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <h1 class="text align-self-center p-2">item 1</h1>
        <h4 class="text align-self-center p-2">item 2</h4>
        <button class="btn btn-danger align-self-center p-2" type="button" name="button">item 3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</section>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add css styles:
`<style type="text/css">
    html, body{
      height: 100%;
    }

    .full-page{
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
</style>`

Answer (score 24):

flexbox can help you. [info here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height: 100px;">
    <div class="p-2">
     1
    </div>
    <div class="p-2">
     2
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19):

Bootstrap has text-center to center a text. For example

```
<div class="container text-center">
```

You change the following

```
<div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
```

to the following

```
<div class="row text-center">
```

Answer (score 12):

You need something to center your form into. But because you didn't specify a height for your html and body, it would just wrap content - and not the viewport. In other words, there was no room where to center the item in.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container, .row.justify-content-center.align-items-center {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Also, the `h-100` util class can be used for `height:100%` in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: I now advise to use @ZimSystem 's solution because it doesn't need custom CSS and only makes use of the classes provided by Bootstrap.

Comment: @BramVanroy as you told i used ZimSystem 's solution but it didn't work for me. your solution working on both version 4.0.0 and 4.1.0 update also

Answer (score 11):

None has worked for me, but this one did.

Since the Bootstrap 4 `.row` class is now `display: flex`, you can simply use the new `align-self-center` flexbox utility on any column to vertically center it.

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-6 align-self-center">
      <div class="card card-block">
      Center
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
      <div class="card card-inverse card-danger">
      Taller
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I learned about it from [this](https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-4-vertical-center-1211448a2eff) Medium article.

Answer (score 10):

Try the code given below while using `v4` or `v5`.

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height:100vh;">
  Vertically and Horizontally Aligned :)
</div>
```

...OR... You can use these classes if using `v5`.

```
<div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
  Vertically and Horizontally Aligned :)
</div>
```

Do this, and that's it :)

Comment: Falls flat on it's face when you want to use mobile.

Comment: Let me know which code, the first one or the second? I use this mostly whenever I need to build a login form. I always test it on all possible devices, but never something like this happened as you mentioned. 

Answer (score 9):

#### Bootstrap 5 (Updated 2024)

There are several suggestions involving bad practices, such as using pure CSS, a combination of Bootstrap classes with custom CSS, or even unnecessary Bootstrap classes.

Below, you can find the minimum required code to achieve the desired result **natively**, with an in-depth analysis for those seeking a better understanding.

##### TL;DR:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <p>This content is centered vertically and horizontally.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

#### In-depth explanation:

1. **vh-100:**

   - **Purpose:** This class sets the height of the element to 100% of the [viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) height.
   - **Behind the scenes:** Bootstrap applies the `height: 100vh;` CSS property, making the container take up the entire height of the viewport.
   - ```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
         <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
         <style>
             .outer-container {
                 border: 2px solid red; 
             }
             .inner-content {
                 border: 2px solid blue; 
             }
         </style>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div class="vh-100 outer-container">
             <p class="inner-content">vh-100 applied.</p>
         </div>
     </body>
     </html>
     ```
2. **d-flex:**

   - **Purpose:** This class is used to enable the [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) layout for the container. Flexbox is a one-dimensional layout method for laying out items in rows or columns.
   - **Behind the scenes:** Bootstrap applies the `display: flex;` CSS property to the element, making it a flex container. This allows you to use properties like [justify-content](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp#justify-content) and [align-items](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp#align-items) to control the alignment of its children.
   - More information about `display` property can be found [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/display/).
   - ```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
         <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
         <style>
             .outer-container {
                 border: 2px solid red; 
             }
             .inner-content {
                 border: 2px solid blue; 
             }
         </style>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div class="vh-100 d-flex outer-container">
             <p class="inner-content">vh-100 and d-flex applied.</p>
         </div>
     </body>
     </html>
     ```
3. **justify-content-center:**

   - **Purpose:** This class is used to horizontally align the child elements (content) of the flex container to the center.
   - **Behind the scenes:** Bootstrap applies the `justify-content: center;` CSS property to the flex container, ensuring its children are horizontally centered.
   - ```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
         <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
         <style>
             .outer-container {
                 border: 2px solid red; 
             }
             .inner-content {
                 border: 2px solid blue; 
             }
         </style>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div class="vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center outer-container">
             <p class="inner-content">vh-100 and d-flex and justify-content-center applied.</p>
         </div>
     </body>
     </html>
     ```
4. **align-items-center:**

   - **Purpose:** This class is used to vertically align the child elements (content) of the flex container to the center.
   - **Behind the scenes:** Bootstrap applies the `align-items: center;` CSS property to the flex container, ensuring its children are vertically centered.
   - ```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
         <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
         <style>
             .outer-container {
                 border: 2px solid red; 
             }
             .inner-content {
                 border: 2px solid blue; 
             }
         </style>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div class="vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center outer-container">
             <p class="inner-content">vh-100 and d-flex and justify-content-center and align-items-center applied.</p>
         </div>
     </body>
     </html>
     ```

Answer (score 4):

This is working in **IE 11** with Bootstrap **4.3**. While the other answers were not working in IE11 in my case.

```
 <div class="row mx-auto justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column ">
    <div class="col-6">Something </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the only thing that happend for me without using d-flex. Thanks Syed!

Answer (score 2):

From bootstrap v5.0 just:

```
<div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
   centred
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap way

HTML

```
 <div class="row top-row">
        <div class="col center-text">
            <H1>Center Text Horizantally and vertically</H1>
        </div>
</div>
```

Custom CSS

```
  .top-row{
        height: 300px; //It's important to set height 
    }
  .center-text{
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="col-12 border border-info">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height: 100px">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Transfer</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark mr-2 ml-2">Replenish</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark mr-3">Account Details</a>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here because I was having an issue with Bootstrap 4 grid system and an Angular *ngFor loop.  I fixed it by applying a col justify-content-center class to the div implementing the ngFor:

```
<div class="row" style="border:1px solid red;">
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button mat-raised-button>text</button>
  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let text of buttonText" class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button mat-raised-button>text</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

which gives the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

been going thru a lot of posts on getting a form centered in the page and none of them worked.  code below is from a react component using bootstrap 4.1.  height should be 100vh and not 100%

```
<div className="container">
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style={height}>
        <form>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input className="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email" type="email"/>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input className="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <button className="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

where height in style is:

```
const height = {
    height: '100vh'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am required to show form vertically center inside container-fluid so I developed my own code for the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
       .container-fluid
       {
            display: table-cell;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw !important;
            vertical-align: middle;
            border:1px solid black;
       }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 offset-2">
                <div class="card shadow">
                    <div class="card-header bg-danger text-white">
                        <h2>Login</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="txtemail" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="email" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" class="form-control" required />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="txtpassword" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="password" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword" class="form-control"
                                        required />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Login</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block">clear all</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's `m-auto` is your friend!

If you have some parent container you want to suspend your content in the middle of, all you need are [`h-100`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/sizing/), [`d-flex`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/), and [`m-auto`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/):

```html
<div class="h-100 d-flex">
  <div class="m-auto">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

The outer container will inflate to the size of whatever container it itself exists in, and the inner container will have `auto` margins set on each of its sides to center it within the parent.

```css
div > div { border: 1px solid red; }
div { border: 1px solid blue; }
body { border: 1px dashed orange; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body class="m-2" style="width: 600px; height: 150px;">
  <div class="h-100 d-flex">
    <div class="m-auto">
      This content is centered<br>
      both vertically and horizontally<br>
      in its container
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

(Where the document body is dashed in orange, the inner `<div>` container is in blue, and the child container in red.)

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap 5

```
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/sign-in/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: also add vh-100 and that's all

Answer (score -1):

Use This Code In CSS :

```css
.container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the doc (bootsrap 4):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content

```css
.justify-content-start
.justify-content-end
.justify-content-center
.justify-content-between
.justify-content-around
.justify-content-sm-start
.justify-content-sm-end
.justify-content-sm-center
.justify-content-sm-between
.justify-content-sm-around
.justify-content-md-start
.justify-content-md-end
.justify-content-md-center
.justify-content-md-between
.justify-content-md-around
.justify-content-lg-start
.justify-content-lg-end
.justify-content-lg-center
.justify-content-lg-between
.justify-content-lg-around
.justify-content-xl-start
.justify-content-xl-end
.justify-content-xl-center
.justify-content-xl-between
.justify-content-xl-around
```