# Best practice to center a div on Bootstrap 4 and use rows within it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am practising in Bootstrap 4 and I do not know what rule I have violated for the responsive design. I am looking for a best practice to carry out the image. My idea is to learn.

[image]

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid h-100" style="border: solid red 1px">
    <div class="row h-100 d-flex   justify-content-center align-items-center contenedor_centrado">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 border">
            1
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 border">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 border">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 border">4</div>
        <div class="col-6 border">5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution with just classes.**

> `my-auto` class to the inner block will place it in the center.

One problem will still be there:

You will have to stretch the outer container using `height:100vh;` so it's stretched to it's screen size.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex flex-column" style="height:100vh; border:5px solid red;">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column my-auto" style="border: solid blue 1px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 border">
            1
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 border">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 border">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 border">4</div>
      <div class="col-6 border">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. but it's very different from my image

Comment: answer my question ... but I need to achieve it with the best practice using only bootstrap 4 classes

Comment: Check the code with just classes. But take care of one issue that we got.

Comment: `flex-column` is used just so it stays in a horizontal layout. Try changing it with `flex-row`, you will figure out what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to solve it:

```
<body>
<div class="h-50">
</div>
  <div style="border: solid blue 1px" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 border">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 border">
          2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 border">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 border">4</div>
    <div class="col-6 border">5</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

I hope it is usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest Bootstrap way using the [flexbox classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/)...

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" style="border: solid red 1px">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center contenedor_centrado">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 border">
            1
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 border">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 border">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="row w-100">
        <div class="col-6 border">4</div>
        <div class="col-6 border">5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/aZnnbWrMRE

Also see:
[Vertical Align Center in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252443/vertical-align-center-in-bootstrap-4/42252877#42252877)
[Bootstrap 4. Center Vertical and Horizontal Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388989/bootstrap-4-center-vertical-and-horizontal-alignment)

Comment: thanks, but div with text "3" not have the same height of the picture... body with heigh:100% not works?

Comment: It's not the same height because you used `align-items-center` on the parent row. Remove that at it works: https://www.codeply.com/go/aZnnbWrMRE