# How to center content generated by *ngFor in a bootstrap grid?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-grid

I would like to center some content in a row using the Bootstrap grid system.  I have looked at many examples about this including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42388989/4440629), but my example differs because of the use of a separate angular component to generate the content.

app.component.html:

```
<div class="row" style="border:1px solid red;">
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button mat-raised-button>text</button>
    <app-child-component></app-child-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

child-component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let text of buttonText">
  <button mat-raised-button>{{text}}</button>
</div>
```

child-component.ts:

```
buttonText = ['Button1', 'Button2', 'Button3'];
```

This gives the result:
[image]

But I would like all buttons to be horizonally aligned:
[image]
StackBlitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-t6uyxp-z6is8f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild-component%2Fchild-component.component.ts

Comment: Would the class `d-flex` on child-component work for you? https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-t6uyxp-v8lzq8?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add display: flex to the wrapper container:

Better to add class instead of inline style. Inlining was done for demo only

```html
<div style="display:flex">
  <div *ngFor="let text of buttonText">
    <button mat-raised-button>{{text}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```