# Align div to adjacent div in Bootstrap columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment, multiple-columns, bootstrap-5

Is it possible to vertically align content within a Bootstrap column to the content of another div?

I have two columns, A and B that are adjacent to each other.
When items in Column B are clicked, a list of words appears in column A.
I would like this collection of words in A to be vertically centered around the selected word in B.

Here is a JSFiddle with a basic idea of what's going on, without the vertical centering

https://jsfiddle.net/so4902r8/5/

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2 offset-4">   
    <div id="wordList1">
      [text]
    </div>
    <div id="wordList2">
      [text]
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="clickMes" class="col-2">
    <div id="clickMe1">
      <a onClick="clickMe1()">Click Me 1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="clickMe2">
      <a onClick="clickMe2()">Click Me 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function clickMe1() {
var x = document.getElementById("wordList1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
x.style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("wordList2").style.display = "none";
  } else {
x.style.display = "none";
  }
}


function clickMe2() {
var x = document.getElementById("wordList2");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("wordList1").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically this would be a duplicate of [Vertical Align Center in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252443/vertical-align-center-in-bootstrap) and [Bootstrap Center Vertical and Horizontal Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388989/)

However, the top padding applied by this CSS rule would prevent `align-items-center` from working as expected...

```
.clickMes {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Therefore, remove the top padding and use `align-items-center` on the row.

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/Oeis5766Ai)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this is not what I am looking for for two reasons.


1 - The words in Column A are not vertically centered around the clicked word in Column B. For example, if I click 'Click Me 1', the word 'Intellegam' should be adjacent to the left of 'Click Me 1', but it is below it


2 - The words in Column B move around vertically, both when words first appear, and when the words change. I would like Column B to be vertically fixed