# how do i position an svg/div to the center vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i am trying to position this div to the center using bootstrap

```
    <section>
        <div class="container position-absolute">
            <div>
                <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 600" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <rect width="600" height="600" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
                    </svg>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44801382/3885246).

Make sure to make room for the vertical centering with `h-100` on the containers.
And then use `justify-content-center` and `align-items-center` for the horizontal and vertical centering.

`container` has some max-width properties. Use `container-fluid`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid position-absolute h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 600" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="600" height="600" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
</svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```